# Is it possible in LEX to show the Related List Contacts on Account-View as List instead of Cards?

Tags: page-layout, lightning-experience, related-list, flexipages

Can I make the RL for Contacts look like Projects below? It should be a table-sytle - not a cards-style

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is coming in Spring 17 release. You can edit the page using Lightning App Builder. You can click on the 'Related Lists' (not Related List) component and select the way they need to be displayed. You will see three options: Default, List and Card. Select List and all the related list will display in the familiar tabular format.